# Pass an arithmetic operator as parameter to rails method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to pass an arithmetic operator ( *, +, -, /) as a parameter to a ruby method? I have seen this performed in C++. Is rails capable of something similar?

```
def calculate(operator)
   1254 operator 34
end

puts calculate(+)
```

Comment: well it's fundamentally a "ruby" method, not rails. also, (*, +, -, /) are usually methods themselves. have you tried to use blocks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
def calculate(op)
  1254.send(op, 34)
end

puts calculate(:+)
```

This works for any method, including the defined arithmetic operators. Note that you need to send the method name as a symbol or string.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a block, and do something like

```
def calculate
  yield 1254,34
end
calculate &:+ # => 1288
```

Comment: This is awesome *+1*. please explain the code a bit. I am getting stupid to understand fully.

Comment: Thanks @OMG, check this  http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby/

Answer (score 4):

Operators desugar to messages. So you can pass a symbol that names the message you want to send.

```
def calculate(operator)
    1254.send(operator, 34)
end

# to call:
puts calculate(:+)
```

Note, of course, that this will allow you to call *any* method, so if you're going to be accepting user input when you're doing this sort of thing, you'll usually want to whitelist.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with `Object#send` or `Object#public_send` methods:

```
def calculate(operator)
  # specify accepted operators here:
  raise ArgumentError unless [:*, :+, :-, :/].include? operator.to_sym
  1254.public_send(op, 34)
end
```